# Update Attribute based on spatial location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, vector, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I want to spatially (Spatial Join) update few fields, not all, from another feature class.

Is there any way to select and update few fields instead of all the fields from the other layer and spatially update them directly into the target feature class?

I am working in SDE environment.

Comment: Yeah - you can use Model Builder/Python and the "Field Mapping" Technique to accomplish this.

Comment: While technically correct, this Answer could be improved with some additional details. For example, links to the ArcMap help pages for more detail, a brief description of the steps involved, common mistakes to beware of, etc.

Comment: Dear Responders, Can you just provide any sample python script, model and field mapping example for the above task. i am new to the ESRI platform, thus doesn't have much knowledge of python, model builder etc.